# JDBC ResultSet.getWarnings

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When the method `getWarnings` of `ResultSet` will really returns a `SQLWarning` ? I am using Oracle Thin Driver, I tried data conversion, for example, converting `12345.678` to a java int. I did not see any warning.

Can anyone show an example that produces a `SQLWarning` from `getWarnings` method of `ResultSet`?

Comment: This is IMO database (and possible also JDBC driver) specific, so please provide apropriate tag. **IMHO** for Oracle can the `getWarnings` be safely ignored; although I have no evidence for this claim.

Comment: How should a type cast in Java generate a SQL warning? Show us your code for which you expect a warning. But even for _implicit_ type casts (either on SQL level or by using a "wrong" getter method) no warning will be issued.

Comment: Actually I just want to know when `getWarning` of `ResultSet` will really get a `SQLWarning`. I tried the data conversion I thought there would be a warning but apparently I did not get one.

Answer (score 1):

With the Oracle Database JDBC drivers the following will result in SQLWarnings:

- Set the fetch direction to anything other than FETCH_FORWARD
- Try to create a scrollable or updatable result set with a query that does not support such
- If the execution returns a PLSQL compiler warning

I can't find anything else that results in a warning.